# Processing document class options with l3keys

Tags: expl3, documentclass-writing, optional-arguments, class-options, l3keys

How can I parse (that is, access) the entire option list given to the current document class with `l3keys`?

This would obviously need some sort of

```
\keys_define:nn { document-class-?? }
 {
  default .code:n { \PassOptionToClass { \l_keys_key_tl } { article } }
 }
```

but I don't know where to look for the document-class option list to give to `\keys_set:nn`.

Comment: Looking at some of my code, I see I've used `\ProvidesExplClass` and `\ProcessKeysOptions{<my choice of prefix>}` where `<my choice of prefix>` is what I've used in the `\keys_define:nn`.  So I think that `l3keys` has this functionality built in.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Doesn't seem to be working; `\ProcessKeysOptions` seems to be undefined. [Refer](https://github.com/vermiculus/smp/blob/move-keys-to-dc/doc/cs-smp.cls#L23)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `l3keys` modules provides general purpose keyval processing for `expl3` code. However, it does not interact with LaTeX2e's package or class option system. For that, you need to load some additional code, which is available in the package `l3keys2e`. This provides the `\ProcessKeysOptions`command to parse class/package options and process them using keyvals defined by `l3keys`.

The reason for this separation is that `l3keys` is intended to form part of a LaTeX3 kernel, while `l3keys2e` is tied to the LaTeX2e model for processing options. It seems extremely likely that a stand-alone LaTeX3 kernel will use keyval options 'natively' but with a different underlying implementation.

Comment: It *seems* that the options are getting set, but I can't manage to suppress the warning of `LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [minp=25,maxp=30].` where I'm still getting the correct warnings. (I implemented target page bounds.)

Comment: @SeanAllred I'll need a demo for that!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/vermiculus/8118405#file-mwe-log-L262

Comment: @JosephWright I'm facing exactly the same trouble as Sean Allred. Do you see what's going on?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé MWE (by e-mail or whatever)? I think the problem in Sean's example is `\LoadClassWithOptions` not with `l3keys2e`.

Comment: @SeanAllred A while, I know, but prompted by Denis's comment I took a look at your MWE. The issue seems to be `\LoadClassWithOptions` as it passes all of the options to `article`, and `article` knows `draft` but not the others.

Comment: @JosephWright I didn't post any MWE because Sean's one is just fine :) About `\LoadClassWithOptions` versus `\PassOptionsToClass ... \LoadClass`, even after `clsguide`'s reading, I'm not sure to understand all those subtleties or, better, I'm sure to not understand them. Complete examples in `l3keys2e` would be sooooooo welcome :)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I took a look at `clsguide` too and I think this particular area is 'undefined' (it's assumed that if you do `\LoadClassWithOptions` its because the wrapper class uses non of them). This is really nothing specific to `l3keys2e` so I'm not sure it fits in to the docs. I'll perhaps add something to my blog.

Comment: @JosephWright It would be very nice to read something about this on your blog: usually, as soon as you write something there, it becomes understandable! :)